# Failure to install VirtualBox 4.2.4 Guest Additions for Linux

Tags: virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux

Trying to install Guest Additions I see:

```
sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

> `The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following module compilation fails then this could be the reason. The missing package can be probably installed with yum install kernel-devel-2.6.18-194.el5`
>
> `Building the main Guest Additions module                   [FAILED]`

Trying to install kernel-devel-2.6.18-194.el5 I see:

```
yum install kernel-devel-2.6.18-194.el5
```

> `Setting up Install Process
>   No package kernel-devel-2.6.18-194.el5 available.
>   Nothing to do`

What can be done with that?

Host OS is Windows 7 64 bit, Guest OS is RedHat 5.5 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `kernel-headers-2.6.18-194.el5`.

It worked for me on Debian

Usually `yum install kernel-headers` picks the correct version by itself

Comment: +1 , assuming this will install devel kernel packages. **which solves the problem.**

Comment: @Znau I simply found that in Debian the devel package comes under the headers name. It just worked *for me*

Comment: i normally just install dkms package and gcc. dkms depends on the devel kernel packages so it works for me.